# What does the clause ''this is done'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, verbs

In this following context, what does the clause ''this is done'' mean?
Does the verb ''done'' stand in for the above verb ''speak''?

Please simplify this to me...

The context:

> 'Thus, when the Buddhist scriptures speak of persons, or even of the
> rebirth of persons, this is done only for the sake of easier
> understanding, and is not to be taken in the sense of ultimate truth.'

Source:
Page. 7
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: "This" refers to "**the speaking** of persons, or of the rebirth of persons in the scriptures".

"done" is the past participle of "do". Another word for it is "**performed**".

 
Stories written in the scriptures are there to facilitate your understanding of more complex concepts (ideas that are difficult to grasp without down-to-earth examples). You don't necessarily have to take them literally.

Answer (score 1):

This is the passive voice

This is done (by something) =  Something does this.

In your example the "by something" is implied to be "the Buddhist scriptures", and "do this" is a stand-in for "speak of persons, or even of the rebirth of persons"

So the meaning is

> The Buddhist scriptures do this only for the sake of easier understanding.

or even more fully,

> The Buddhist scriptures speak of persons, or even of the rebirth of persons, only for the sake of easier understanding, and it is not to be taken in the sense of ultimate truth.'

Answer (score 0):

this is done only for the sake of easier understanding=this was spoken  only for the sake of easier understanding